# login to postgresql with md5 password

Tags: postgresql, md5

I read the documentation on www.postgresql.org and there is [this text about md5 login](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/auth-password.html):

> The method `md5` uses a custom less secure challenge-response mechanism. It prevents password sniffing and avoids storing passwords on the server in plain text but **provides no protection if an attacker manages to steal the password hash from the server**. Also, the MD5 hash algorithm is nowadays no longer considered secure against determined attacks.

Does that mean, if I know the md5 hash stored in the database, I can connect remotely with the md5 hash instead of the plain password itself? If so, how can I do this? The ODBC driver I am using seems to only allow plain text password to enter, and not md5 hash. Are there any possibilities for doing this?

Comment: It means that if you know the md5 hash, you can know the plain text password within a few seconds. So count how much time you want to spend to allow transmitting hashed password in order to make an attacker loose a few seconds.

Comment: How can I get the plain text password, if I know the md5 hash? The plain text password isn't stored in the database, only the md5 hash, or am I wrong?

Comment: You can search for "postgres md5 crack" ... And soon after you will want the new scram-sha-256 instead of md5

Comment: @JGH nonsense.  Unless your password is 5 letters or less or a common dictionary word, you won't get in a few seconds.  And the threat model is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any client which will do this for you out-of-the-box.  It is trivially easy to change the client source code to do this, and compile a new 'hackerized' client.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. All you need is the hashed password. The idea behind hashing it is that if the password is stolen, the thief cannot try the same password with other accounts.

To authenticate with the hashed password, you have to speak the [line protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-message-formats.html) with the server — you'll receive a “AuthenticationMD5Password” and answer with a “GSSResponse”.

All the drivers do the first hashing step for you; see for example this piece of code from the JDBC driver:

```java
/**
 * Encodes user/password/salt information in the following way: MD5(MD5(password + user) + salt)
 *
 * @param user The connecting user.
 * @param password The connecting user's password.
 * @param salt A four-salt sent by the server.
 * @return A 35-byte array, comprising the string "md5" and an MD5 digest.
 */
public static byte[] encode(byte[] user, byte[] password, byte[] salt) {
  MessageDigest md;
  byte[] temp_digest;
  byte[] pass_digest;
  byte[] hex_digest = new byte[35];

  try {
    md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

    md.update(password);
    md.update(user);
    temp_digest = md.digest();

    bytesToHex(temp_digest, hex_digest, 0);
    md.update(hex_digest, 0, 32);
    md.update(salt);
    pass_digest = md.digest();

    bytesToHex(pass_digest, hex_digest, 3);
    hex_digest[0] = (byte) 'm';
    hex_digest[1] = (byte) 'd';
    hex_digest[2] = (byte) '5';
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to encode password with MD5", e);
  }

  return hex_digest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'd like to create an application in VB.net, where I would like to use only the md5 hashed password, and I can't use the cleartext password itself. But as I can see with npgsql it isn't possible to provide the hashed password. Do you know any other methods in VB.net, or do I need to create the whole SQL client myself?

Comment: easiest is probably to fork npgsql